# .getIntExtra returning 0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been writing a quiz app, and i want to pass the score from one activity to the next one(one question to the other, and then to the final page where you can see your score). But I always get 0 at the end, i guess because it is the default int value I set.

Here's the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.example.leodr.testedeinwissen.Frage2");
i.putExtra("score", score);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the next activity:

```
int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);
```

i also tried SharedPreferences but that didnt work either.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
spe.putInt("score", (int)score);
spe.commit();
```

And in the second activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
score = sp.getInt("score", 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here's the code:
>
> ```
> Intent i = new Intent("com.example.leodr.testedeinwissen.Frage2");
> i.putExtra("score", score);
> startActivity(i);
> ```

The first line here will not work, though the next two lines are fine. Your first line is making use of the `Intent(String)` constructor, and this constructor only specifies the *action* for the `Intent`. You will most likely want to use the `Intent(Context, Class)` constructor instead, with code like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Frage2.class);
```

As for your second problem...

> i also tried SharedPreferences but that didnt work either.
>
> ```
> SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
> SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
> spe.putInt("score", (int)score);
> spe.commit();
> ```
>
> And in the second activity:
>
> ```
> SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
> score = sp.getInt("score", 0);
> ```

You are using the `Activity.getPreferences()` call here, which returns a `SharedPreferences` instance that is **private to each activity**. In other words, `getPreferences()` in your second activity is going to return a *different* `SharedPreferences` than the `getPreferences()` call in your first activity.

If you want to use `SharedPreferences` to share values between multiple activities, you should use the `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` call instead, and pass the same value for the `String` (`name`) parameter both times. Maybe something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ScoreStorage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
spe.putInt("score", (int)score);
spe.commit();
```

And in the second activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ScoreStorage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
score = sp.getInt("score", 0);
```